# How to use android.util.Log in the extra module of Android?

Tags: android, logging

I am developing an Android app with Clean Architecture.
So I separated the modules to 'app', 'data', 'domain'.

But what I want to do is using an android.utils.Log in the module 'data', 'domain'.

I cannot find it in the 'data', 'domain' modules.

Below is my 'domain' module's gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
```

Should I add something in here?

Or should I just use "System.out.println()" method?

Comment: you don't have to use `apply plugin: 'java-library'` for the android modules. If you want to use android features (**android**.util.log), you have to make it Android module

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have to confirm your intentions are good :)

You need to do the following to achieve what you want:

1. Define final `Log` class + interface defining log, both in your `domain`:

   ```
   public final class Log {
    private static LogInterface logInterface;

    public static void d(String tag, String message) {
       logInterface.d(tag, message);
    }

    public static void setLogInterface(LogInterface logInterface) {
        Log.logInterface = logInterface;
    }

    public interface LogInterface {
       void d(String tag, String message);
       //...
    }
   }
   ```

Notice all of the above are pure java, nothing bound to android.

2. In any of your android modules, create and implement android logger:

   ```
   public class AndroidLog implements Log.LogInterface {
    public void d(String tag, String message) {
       android.util.Log.d(tag, message);
    }
   }
   ```
3. Probably in the same module as p2, initialize (initialization likely should happen when app is created) :

   ```
   Log.setLogInterface(new AndroidLogger());
   ```

Now you can use your domain's Log like this: Log.d(...) - all around in your pure java modules.

Comment: Sorry SO formatting isn't working well for the above.